# Phonegap Build Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap

running:

```
phonegap build android
```

with android SDK and Java SDK installed, I get the following error:

Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.

I have tried adding the "java\jdk-9\bin" to environment variables, and PATH, etc. No luck!

My suspicion is that phonegap is trying to use the runtime version of Java as opposed to the SDK.

Comment: Not sure if this is a step forwards, but the new error is: Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater. JDK 1.9 is installed, a java -version confirms 9+181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and I solved it by uninstalling jdk-9 and installing [JDK version 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Then set up the environment variables where needed (JAVA_HOME & add \bin to Path)

Comment: That is exactly what I did last night and it worked. It asks for a version > 8, which I always thought 9 was... Anyway, solved now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other users find this info useful. I'm windows user.

I spent so much time on this issue and realized that git-bash can't get it work and command prompt launch it without any issue! Many things i have did before switched to command prompt.

1. update to latest JDK8 Update
2. add \bin to Path.